# Retrieving current value of angular select div

Tags: angular, data-binding, html-select

I need to get the current chosen value of select label, becuase the next label data depends on this selected above day.
My html for the label looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for ="visitData">Choose day for the visit : </label>
          <select  class="form-control" id="visitData" (change) = "updateVisitDate($event)" >
            <option   id="visitData" *ngFor="let type of myDate" value="{{type.date}}">{{type.date}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

The function in TypeScript file:

```
  updateVisitDate(event:any){
    event.preventDefault()
    let target = event.target;
    this.visitData = target.querySelector('#visitData').value;
    console.log("Found date : "+ this.visitData);
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:9000/freeHours/getDay`,{params : {date:this.visitData}}).subscribe(data=>this.periods = data);
  }
```

Whenever i change the day from the select field i get in the log the same day(first option). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property binding,

`[value]="type.date"` and to get value , use `event.target.value` in your function.
i.e `this.visitData = event.target.value;`

Here is a working demo for your problem
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oygbwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have tried that already and it didn't change the outcome. The log looks like this:
4make-visit.component.ts:117 found date : Wed, 24-02-2021

Comment: use this.visitData = event.target.value